# Assume $G$ is an Abelian group containing an element of order greater than $2$, then provide a nonidentity automorphism in $G$.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, automorphism-group

Assume $G$ is an Abelian group containing an element of order greater than $2$, then provide a nonidentity automorphism in $G$.

---

Let $\Psi:G \to G$ be a mapping given by $g \mapsto g^{\text{ord}(g_1)}$ and let  $g_1  \in G$ be the element with order greater than $2$ then for $g,h \in G$
$$\Psi(gh)=(gh)^{\text{ord}(g_1)}=g^{\text{ord}(g_1)}h^{\text{ord}(g_1)}=\Psi(g)\Psi(h)$$

And this is indeed true since $G$ is Abelian.

Now we need to show that the kernel of the mapping contains only the identity element of $G$ denoted by $e$ but I think the mapping is not the one that is useful since $\Psi(g_1)=g_1^{\text{ord}(g_1)}=e$ which follows that $g_1 \in \text{ker}(\Psi)$ and $g_1$ is not necessarily identical to $e$ and hence the mapping is not necessarily an injection.

So what mapping will be useful and how can I finish the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mapping $\phi: g \mapsto g^{-1}$ is the desired automorphism. It is not equal to identity because $\phi(g_1)\not= g_1$.

Note that in the non-Abelian case, $\phi$ is not a morphism in $G$. It is a isomorphism from $G$ to its opposite group in this case.

Comment: Yes, the proof is correct .

Comment: If you read the proof, then it should be clear where that property is used. If there was no element of order greater than 2 then $\phi$ would be the identity map.

Comment: Let ord($g_1)=n\in \Bbb N$ with $n\ge 3$. Let $H$ be the $n$-element subgroup generated by $\{g_1\}$. Since $G$ is Abelian, $G$ is isomorphic to $(G/H)\times H.$ Since $n\ge 3$ there exists $m\in \Bbb N$ with $n>m>1$ and $\gcd(m,n)=1.$ So for $x=(y, (g_1)^j)\in (G/H)\times H$ let $\phi(x)=(y,(g_1)^{mj}).$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet This would deserve another answer since you find other automorphisms. It seems to me that if $G\not = \{e, g_1, g_1^2\}$, there are always at least two automorphisms that satisfy the problem.

Comment: If G is the cyclic group with 4 members then there are just 2 automorphisms of G and one of them is id_G.